# Using non-sequential vector as input for a loop

Tags: r, loops, vector

I experience some problems with the loop function in R and couldn't find an answer on this question on this website. I would like to use a numeric vector as input for a loop in R.

For example:

```
ns <- c(10, 20, 40, 80, 160)

for (n in ns) {
 ni[n] <- round(rnorm(1, mean = n, sd = 1))
}
```

The result of this code is a vector with 155 times NA and five correct values in this vector. However, I would like to get rid of all those NAs and get a vector with only the five correct values. I know how to select the correct values from the vector with the 155 NA, but I prefer to obtain a proper vector directly after running the loop.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember that many functions in R are vectorized

```
> rnorm(length(ns), mean=ns)
[1]   9.905652  19.721717  40.462751  78.982971 160.770257
```

(in your question, `ni[n]` creates a vector as long as the maximum of `n`, i.e., 160 elements).

It's interesting to see this evolve from an `sapply` solution offered by @VictorK.

```
sapply(ns, function(n) round(rnorm(1, mean = n, sd = 1)))
```

factor out the `round` and drop the default argument `sd = 1`, so

```
round(sapply(ns, function(n) rnorm(1, mean = n)))
```

then recognize that `rnorm` could replace the anonymous function `function(n) ...` if we name it's first argument in the `sapply` call. The first argument of `rnorm` is named `n`, so things are a little confusing; but we're forcing the elements of `ns` to match the second argument `mean`. For instance the first time through the sapply we evaluate `rnorm(ns[[1]], n=1)`. R matches arguments first by name, so n=1 matches the first argument of `rnorm`, and then by position amongst the remaining arguments, so the unnamed argument `ns[[1]]` matches the next available argument, `mean`)

```
round(sapply(ns, rnorm, n = 1))
```

and then perhaps we see the fully vectorized solution

```
round(rnorm(n = length(ns), mean = ns))
```

Answer (score 7):

@Martin Morgan has shown you how to do this properly for the particular example you give. However, let's presume you want to use a function that isn't vectorised or you want to do something else along the lines of you actual example.

One way of doing that is to iterate over the *indices* of the elements of `ns`, not the elements themselves. Consider

```
ns <- c(10, 20, 40, 80, 160)
ni <- numeric(length = length(ns)) ## pre-allocate storage

for (n in seq_along(ns)) {
  ni[n] <- round(rnorm(1, mean = ns[n], sd = 1))
}

> ni
[1]  12  21  40  80 160
```

The key differences are

- the use of `seq_along()` to get R to generate a 1, 2, 3, ... sequence that is as long as `ns`, and
- using `n` as an index into `ns` to select the correct value rather than using the value of `n` itself.

For this example it is wasteful to call `rnorm()` `lenght(ns)` times, but there are occasions where doing something like this does make sense and indexing via the loop variable rather than using the loop variable itself is a handy approach.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to create a vector on the fly. Here are a few options:

1) With a loop (but see for the next solution, as you should try to avoid loops in R):

```
ns <- c(10, 20, 40, 80, 160)

ni <- numeric(length(ns)) # pre-allocate the resulting vector
for (i in 1:length(ns)) {
  ni[i] <- round(rnorm(1, mean = ns[i], sd = 1))
}
```

2) Using apply family of functions:

```
sapply(ns, function(n) round(rnorm(1, mean = n, sd = 1)))
```

The second one is an idiomatic R.

Comment: You point about avoiding loops in R but suggesting that the `sapply()` is better is not specific enough. Both of your examples form loops in R it just so happens that `sapply()` does a little more of the loop in compiled code compared to `for`, but where the body of the loop is the dominant amount of compute time, that `sapply()` uses compiled loop code is largely irrelevant and both solutions will have very similar execution times. The aversion to loops in R is often a hangover from S-Plus days or due to writing poor R code.

Comment: @GavinSimpson - thanks for the clarification. I agree that execution time may by similar in many cases. I think the main advantage of ``sapply()`` is that it promotes a better coding style.

Comment: I actually think that an aversion to writing `for` loops often people to write convoluted `*apply` code/functions when a `for()` loop would be far more natural, easier to understand and less effort.

Answer (score 1):

stumbled across a similar issue when coding..so I thought I'll give my version of a cleaner loop. I would personally use the following construct:

```
ns <- c(10, 20, 40, 80, 160)
ni <- numeric(length = length(ns))  # keeping this as per Victor's earlier post#

y=0  #adding starting counter#
 for (i in ns) {  # ns is already defined with its numeric sequence  on line 1 of the  
                  # code #

   y=y+1 # counter used in the ni vector

  ni[[y]] <- meanX(i)  # preferable to create a custom function but not mandatory
 }

ni  # will produce only the 5 outputs of the rnorm function
    # 11  21  41  81 161


## Custom function  ##
meanX <-function(meanX) {round(rnorm(1, mean = meanX, sd = 1))

  return(round(rnorm(1, mean = meanX, sd = 1)))

  }
##  end of Custom function ##
```